# Alternative to DevExpress to use Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, devexpress, devart

Recently I have been working on a website using a trial version of DevExpress with the latest version of Entity Framework, but my trial has run out.  Is there a free alternative anyone knows of that I could use in it's place? I'd like to keep the whole MVC flow going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress only provides extensions for (and not the root of) MVC. As long as you can go without the extended versions of the charts, tables and other controls you'll be fine. Otherwise, if you're that dead-set on their controls or have a lot invested you may look at just purchasing the package.

Also, to be clear, EF is a freely-available library (if you have NuGet it's [very easy to obtain](http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework)) so anything relying on that is safe:

```
Install-Package Entity-Framework -Version 5.0.0
```

That would install the latest solid build to your project.